# PIL giving error when trying to run Floodfill, need to change to Turtle

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-turtle

Im trying to make a BFS Floodfill with PIL, but i can't find how to fix the import erros, and I need to translate it to Python Turtle

```
from queue import Queue
import queue
from PIL import Image

imagen = Image.open("Imagen.png")
ROJO = (255, 0, 0)
x, y = 0, 0
floodfill(imagen, x, y, ROJO)
imagen.save("ImagenResultado.png")

def floodfill(grid, i, j, nuevo_color):
w = imagen.width
h = imagen.height
viejo_color = imagen.getpixel((x, y))

queue = Queue()
queue.put((x, y))

while not queue.empty():
    x, y = queue.get()
    if x < 0 or x >= w or y < 0 or y >= h or imagen.getpixel((x, y)) != viejo_color:
        continue
    else:
        imagen.putpixel((x, y), nuevo_color)
        queue.put((x+1,y))
        queue.put((x-1,y))
        queue.put((x,y+1))
        queue.put((x,y-1))
```

Comment: What errors? Where specifically are you stuck porting it to turtle?

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `floodfill(...)` before defining it.
and as a bonus tip, you are using `x` and `y` instead of `i` and `j` within the function definition.
I'm assuming that the bad formatting is just an oversight, but if not, the lack of correct whitespace will cause python errors too. None of this is due to PIL.